# How to use insertBefore() in jQuery in a select list

Tags: jquery, selectlist

I have a select list which is dynamically populated, and an insert button. When I click an option in the select list and then click the insert button, a popup opens. In the popup there is a text field where I insert a value and click the OK button of the popup. Now I want that when I click OK, the popup value should be inserted before the selected option of the select list.

```
/*  Please show some example Code Here  */
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Show some code (markup and JavaScript) that we can help you based on. Code speaks more than the words describing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#mySelect option:selected').before($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'My option'
}));
```

Comment: palash, i tried your code.but the problem is the new value is getting inserted before each and every item of the select list. can you tell why this is happening?

Comment: Please post your code and the HTML markup http://jsfiddle.net/. I will look into it.

Comment: There was a bit of mistake in my code. Yours was absolutely correct. Its working fine now. Thanks a lot palash. I needed to complete this today. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var sel = opener.document.getElementById("someSelect");
sel.options[sel.selectedIndex-1].option=new Option("some text","some value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ddlWeeklyWeightIn').on("change", function () {
           $("#ddlWeeklyWeightIn option:selected").insertBefore($("#ddlWeeklyWeightIn option:selected").prev());
        });
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/cn9Fk/)

Hope It helps you.

Comment: Palash's code solved my problem. Thanks anyways for your help & time.